# Does one "shave" or "shear" a dog?

Tags: word-choice

I was [editing a question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28204/is-shaving-siberian-huskies-harmful) about the alleged dangers of shaving a dog.

The associated pictures were like this:

[image: Picture of dog without much hair]

To me, this dog hasn't been *shaved*, i.e. removing all of the hair down to the skin, especially with a blade. This dog has been *shorn* - removing most - not all - of the coat with clippers, or perhaps *clipped*.

Examining a dictionary didn't clarify this distinction, making me wonder if I am making it up.

Is it standard usage to describe clipping the coat from a dog as "shaving", or would correcting it to "shearing" be preferred?

Comment: Why should only one of them be correct?

Comment: *Shorn* is correct.

Comment: @TimRomano *Shorn* is just the pp of *shear*

Comment: @Kris: I don't think I worded the question to imply that only one is correct. Either "shaved", "shorn" and "clipped" are all correct, or only the latter two.

Comment: @TimRomano: If you have an answer, please use the answer box.

Comment: When you say shear, it comes with a connotation of collecting the hair for use afterwards.  So when you shear a dog, I'm thinking that you are going to make a dog-wool coat.  I may be unique in this, but since the hair is not being cut for collection and the hair is not being cut to the skin, I would prefer "trimmed".  As in:  "The dogs fur was trimmed nice and short."

Comment: @Kris: I know. I'm saying that "shave" is the not the correct verb to describe what has been done to the dog. The dog has been shorn, not shaved.

Comment: I think it depends on how fluffy the dog is. If it has little hair, it would be more akin to shaving, but if it has a lot (like a sheep), it'd be closer to shearing.

Comment: Most people have it clipped, some shaved, it would seem from [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shorn+the+dog%2Cclipped+the+dog%2Cshaved+the+dog&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclipped%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshaved%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0) (shorn the dog,clipped the dog,shaved the dog).

Comment: ... ('sheared the dog' flatlines too.)

Comment: @Edwin: Again, I would suggest putting answers in answer boxes.

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't consider my 'answer' well enough substantiated (or even researched: look at Chenmunka's [wife's] telling contribution) to merit 'answer' status.

Comment: In answer to the question in your title:  No.

Comment: I'd say that `shearing` was done with *shears* (scissors) and `shaving` is done with a razor or hair clippers.

Comment: According to the definition of _shear_, it can refer to the cutting of wool, fur, or hair, but it seems to be most commonly used in reference to wool. For me personally, the first thing that comes to mind when I hear the word _shear_ is sheep. Your mileage may vary, however.

Comment: You shave a cat.  You sheer a dog. ...sorry, I just had to and it could have been worse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be a significant diversity in dog grooming terminology. Several popular online resources refer to dogs being *shaved* rather than *shorn*, *clipped* or *stripped*, as in *[The LP Grooming Guide](http://loosepooch.com/images/grooming/LP-grooming-guide.pdf)*, published by the Loose Pooch Kennel Club:

> Cocker Cut ... The face is ***shaved*** and some pet parents like to leave
>   the head furry,while others prefer it to be ***shaved*** along with the top
>   1/3 of the ear...
>
> Poodle Cut(s) ... Typically poodles have ***shaved*** feet and faces, rounded
>   top knots and fluffy hair...
>
> Lion Cut ... The rear end of the body is ***shaved*** close to the
>   skin while the top part is left long to attain the lion look...
>
> Poodle Face: Typically done on poodles, we are (*sic*) ***shave***
>   the face clean and very close to the skin...
>
> Tipped Ears ... Some breed cuts have what we call tipped ears. This
>   means the top 1/3rd of the ear is ***shaved*** leaving sharply pointed ears...
>
> Poodle Feet: Just like the above mentioned clean face, clean feet are
>   completely ***shaved*** exposing the nails and the entire foot up to the
>   ankle area.
>
> GI Cut is a full strip all over the body including the head, ears, and
>   tail. EVERYTHING gets ***shaved***.
>
> Kennel Cut: Many of you out there use this term broadly to mean an all
>   over ***shave*** down. In the dog grooming world, a kennel cut is an all
>   over length set either with a blade or a guide comb, but with clean
>   face and clean feet as well as a topknot.
>
> Fanny: A strip ***shaved*** from the anus down to the belly area for those
>   dogs that are extremely hairy around the backend like Pomeranians and
>   chows...
>
> Shell Out: A shell out is when the belly area is ***shaved*** all the
>   way up to the arm pit area and includes the arm pits...
>   <sub>***Emphasis*** added</sub>

From the online article *[dog grooming terminology and blade uses](http://doggroominginhouston.com/dog-grooming-terminology-and-blade-uses)*, by Hot Shot Dog Grooming:

> The #10 blade is the shortest blade used for ***shave*** downs,
>   leaving the hair short and smooth...
>
> .#5 blade – This blade is great for short cuts, but will not show skin.  It is perfect for sensitive skin or dogs with white hair because those
>   dogs typically show skin when ***shaved*** too short.
>
> Some dogs with undercoat or even those that have straight or wiry hair
>   require a different techniques for ***shaving*** than other fluffier
>   haired dogs.  To create a super smooth look you sometimes need to
>   ***shave*** with a blade in reverse.  “In reverse” is a dog grooming term that simply means you ***shave*** against the grain of the hair,
>   or from the back of the dog toward the front...
>
> Tight Feet – Tight feet are kind of in between clean feet and rounded
>   feet.  They expose the nails, keep the feet free from matting, but are
>   not ***shaved*** close to the skin.
>   <sub>***Emphasis*** added</sub>

The article *[Common Dog Grooming Terms Explained](http://www.petco.com/Content/ArticleList/Article/19/1/7909/Common-Dog-Grooming-Terms-Explained.aspx)*, by Petco, concurs with this popular terminology, as does the *[Canine Groomer’s Glossary](http://www.adambouskila.com/2005/03/18/we-need-a-new-design/)*.

Other popular resources refer to dogs being *clipped* and *shaved*, as in the article *[An Introduction To Clipping Your Dog](http://diydoggrooming.com/grooming/clipping/)*, by DIY Dog Grooming:

> ***Clipping*** is the process of using dog clippers and a blade to ***shave*** the dog short.  The clippers can be used over the body, down the legs and
>   around the face... The face can be either ***shaved*** or if you prefer scissored.
>   <sub>***Emphasis*** added</sub>

Although it is not entirely clear what grooming operation is referred to, The [American Kennel Club](http://www.akc.org/about/glossary/) uses *clip*, but not *shave*, *shear*, or *strip* in their online glossary:

> ***Clip***
>
> The method of trimming the coat on some breeds.

In the UK, *[Grooming terminology](http://www.doggroomingaldershot.co.uk/2013/09/grooming-terminology-what-it-all-means/)*, by 4 Paws Dog and Cat Grooming, uses *clipping* in general, reserving *shave* for a specific type of *clipping* close to the skin:

> As a rule we always prefer to groom your dog according to the
>   characteristics of its breed. That means defining the looks and
>   character of the breed and coat texture, and grooming in line with how
>   best the coat be maintained e.g. ***clipping*** or hand stripping...
>
> This is basically a close ***shave*** to the feet and is typical for breeds
>   such as Poodles and Bedlington Terriers. For Spaniels and similar
>   breeds we’ll clean feet back tidy but won’t ***shave*** them.
>   <sub>***Emphasis*** added</sub>

Although there is ambiguity, the consensus seems to be that *stripping* is a unique grooming operation that uses special tools to pull hairs out by the roots rather than cutting them. The process is described in the article *[Stripping: Reveal Your Wirehaired Dog's Show Quality Coat](http://www.petplace.com/article/dogs/keeping-your-dog-healthy/grooming-your-dog/stripping-reveal-your-wirehaired-dogs-show-quality-coat)*, by Pet Place:

> **Stripping vs. Clipping**
>   A wire hair has a hard point, but is soft near the base. Clipping removes that hard end, and the soft, faded portion grows farther out. Stripping removes the entire hair from the follicle, allowing for a new, wiry, brightly colored hair to grow.

It seems that ***clipping*** is the unmarked expression in the industry, so *clipping* would be a good general term to describe what happened to the dog in the OP. Because the hair was clipped so close to the skin, it also seems appropriate to add specificity by saying that the dog was ***shaved***. Since there is no central authority to determine these grooming definitions, it seems wise for authors to establish working definitions of their terminology, and for speakers to confirm the definitions they are using in conversation.

---

We might have intuited the word *shear*, which seems to be distantly related to *shave* beyond the antiquity of Proto-Indo-European:

*[Shave](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shave&allowed_in_frame=0)*

> Old English sceafan (strong verb, past tense scof, past participle
>   scafen), "to scrape, shave, polish,"
>   from Proto-Germanic *skaban
>   (cognates: Old Norse skafa, Middle Dutch scaven, German schaben,
>   Gothic skaban "scratch, shave, scrape"),
>   ***from PIE skabh-***, collateral
>   form of root ***(s)kep-*** "***to cut, to scrape, to hack***" (see scabies).
>   Related: Shaved; shaving. Original strong verb status is preserved in
>   past tense form shaven.
>   Specifically in reference to cutting the hair
>   close from mid-13c. Figurative sense of "to strip (someone) of money
>   or possessions" is attested from late 14c.
>   *etymonline **emphasis** added*

*[Shear](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shear&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> Old English sceran, scieran (class IV strong verb; past tense scear,
>   past participle scoren) "to cleave, hew, cut with a sharp instrument;
>   cut (hair); shear (sheep),"
>   from Proto-Germanic *sker- "to cut"
>   (cognates: Old Norse and Old Frisian skera, Dutch scheren, German
>   scheren "to shear"),
>   ***from PIE (s)ker-*** (1) "***to cut, to scrape, to
>   hack***"
>   (cognates: Sanskrit krnati "hurts, wounds, kills," krntati
>   "cuts;" Hittite karsh- "to cut off;" Greek keirein "to cut, shear;"
>   Latin curtus "short;" Lithuanian skiriu "to separate;" Old Irish
>   scaraim "I separate;" Welsh ysgar "to separate," ysgyr "fragment").
>   *etymonline **emphasis** added*

A [complementary answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255205/does-one-shave-or-shear-a-dog/255206#255206) discusses the distinction of tools and cutting action associated with *shave* and *shear*. In addition to that distinction, *[shave](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shave)* is now [used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shave%20the%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cshave%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20hair%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20beard%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20heads%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20whole%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20upper%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20crown%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20front%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshave%20the%20beards%3B%2Cc0) predominantly for removing hair from ***humans***, and not so much for animals:

> verb
>
> 1.0 [NO OBJECT] (Of a man) cut the hair off the face with a razor:
>   *he
>   washed, shaved, and had breakfast*
>
> 1.1 [WITH OBJECT] Cut the hair off (a part of the body) with a razor:
>   *she shaved her legs*
>
> 1.2 [WITH OBJECT] Cut the hair off the face or another part of the body of (someone) with a razor:
>   *his wife washed and shaved him*
>
> 1.3 Cut (hair) off with a razor:
>   *professional male swimmers shave off their body hair*
>   *ODO*

In its literal sense, *[shear](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shear)* is predominantly [used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shear%20the%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cshear%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20sheep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20wolf%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20fleece%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20wool%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20flock%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20swine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20rivets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20rivet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20firstling%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshear%20the%20fleeces%3B%2Cc0) for removing hair from ***animals***, and less often for humans :

> verb
>
> 1.0 ... [WITH OBJECT] Cut the wool off (a sheep or other animal):
>   *Paul
>   has never sheared a sheep before*
>   (as noun shearing) *demonstrations of
>   sheep shearing*
>
> 1.1 Cut off (something such as hair, wool, or grass), with scissors or shears:
>   *I’ll shear off all that fleece*
>   *ODO*

Perhaps because they are man's best friend, ***dogs*** seem to be an [exception](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shave%20the%20dog%2C%20shear%20the%20dog&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshave%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0) to this human/animal [distinction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shave%20the%20dog%2Cshear%20the%20dog%2Cclipping%20dogs%2Cstripping%20dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshave%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclipping%20dogs%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Whatever you call it, [removing the hair from a yak](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://mercedescoyle.com/slides/images/yak-shaving.jpg&imgrefurl=http://mercedescoyle.com/slides/leveling-up.html&h=441&w=650&tbnid=FU6yhTiuCwiVbM:&zoom=1&docid=ZC-LraYtgxrLtM&ei=7nuNVZ-EAcTr-QGj4KDwAQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CCEQMygFMAU) can be hazardous to your health!

[image]

Comment: Interesting. One animal that "shaving" applies to is [yaks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving).

Comment: Since what is done to sheep and goats is precisely what is done to yaks, I'd be interested to know why yaks are *shaved* rather than *shorn* :-)

Comment: Yak-shaving **isn't** done. That's the point.

Comment: [Rare, but not non-existent](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://mercedescoyle.com/slides/images/yak-shaving.jpg&imgrefurl=http://mercedescoyle.com/slides/leveling-up.html&h=441&w=650&tbnid=FU6yhTiuCwiVbM:&zoom=1&docid=ZC-LraYtgxrLtM&ei=7nuNVZ-EAcTr-QGj4KDwAQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CCEQMygFMAU), @EdwinAshworth :-)

Comment: Probably inconsequential but [trim the dog](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shave+the+dog%2Cshear+the+dog%2Ctrim+the+dog&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshave%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrim%20the%20dog%3B%2Cc0) is more popular than either.

Comment: @Dispenser, it's only inconsequential in the sense that the OP is comparing *shave* and *shear* in relation to a specific picture. *Trim* is the word I would use to describe what gets done to most dogs, but most don't get their coat chopped to the skin like that :-)

Comment: Please note that the definition for "stripping" is given as *"Stripping removes the entire hair from the follicle,"* This is misleading and ambiguous. Stripping does not remove the hair from the follicle (which would be painful): it cuts away the upper part of the hair leaving behind the undercoat

Comment: @Greybeard- So we agree.  Your contention supports my point that no authority exists to determine the exact definition of these words. They are used interchangeably by various authors and organizations. I demonstrated that “stripping” has one unique narrowly-defined use that does not eliminate any general uses of the term, but did not suggest applying that definition to the operation in the picture. Thanks for keeping this post alive.

Answer (score 20):

My wife is a Dog Groomer.  There are two ways of tidying a dog's coat.  These are the terms used by the Kennel Club in Britain.  The '[Breed Standard](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/activities/dog-showing/breed-standards/)' for a pedigree show dog will define how the coat of a particular breed of dog should be prepared.

**Clipping** is the term used when using either manual or electric clippers.  Even when taking the coat to a very short state.  Thus the dog in the picture has been clipped very short.

**Stripping** is the term for removing the undercoat while leaving the longer hairs trimmed.

The term shaving would only be used if a razor were to be used and that is normally only done for veterinary reasons.

Comment: I'm quite prepared to accept your wife as an authority. But can you ask her how general the use of the terminology is (statewide ... nationwide ... universal; one establishment ... one chain ... universal), please?

Comment: [*Stripping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_grooming#Stripping) seems to be a grooming operation irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: "Clipping" does not describe the grooming operation of the picture!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I've added some detail to address your question.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between to shear and to shave, which lexicographers may or may not clearly describe, lies in the type of cutting implement, which affects the nature of the cut.

One shears with scissors or clippers (or a mechanical device that employs multiple small blades in a scissoring action), whereas one shaves with a single bevel-sharpened blade pressed against the skin.

Anticipating the "what about the electric razor"?  It consists of multiple tiny bevel-sharpened blades each of which presses in turn against the skin, or as close to the skin as the protective shield will allow them to get.

Comment: 'The difference ... which lexicographers may or may not clearly describe' needs backing by some recognised authority.

Comment: But seriously, if a definition simply says "a close cut" and doesn't mention the type of cutting implement or specify what is meant by "close" (as many don't) we have sufficient proof that not all lexicographers have described the words with razor precision..

Comment: Would it count in a published paper?

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shear) licenses a less precise definition: To cut with or as if with shears: _shearing a hedge_. As does Collins: 1. (Agriculture) (tr) to remove (the fleece or hair) of (sheep, etc) by cutting or clipping
2. to cut or cut through (something) with shears or a sharp instrument.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: "as if with shears..." would mean "producing the type of cut produced by shears (i.e. blades in a scissoring action)".  One cannot shave one's face with scissors. But one can emulate a scissors-cut with a razor, since the more precise blade can be used (albeit inefficiently) to produce the less precise cut.

Comment: Apparently, then, [some electric razors at least give you a shear](http://www.paupersdime.com/guide-buying-an-electric-razor-shaver-philips-norelco-braun/). As with mine vs quarry, the words are idiosyncratic in their usages.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: the electric razor does not use a true scissoring motion, despite what the marketing department says.

Comment: I've upvoted ScotM's answer, because he takes the trouble to provide support (though he misses the 'instrument' association you pick up on, perhaps a tad excessively: usage determines acceptability [and see the anomaly with dogs mentioned below]). To quote Matt Gutting: ... What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case an encyclopedia, dictionary, or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support....

Comment: Thank you, @EdwinAshworth. Since Tim had already mentioned the instrument/action connotation, which I believe has **some** merit--even if it is subjective and difficult to document--I found no reason to include it my answer. The **predominance** of the instrument/action distinction may not be as pronounced as the predominance of the human vs. animal distinction, but it is real in my mind.

Comment: AFAIK, [electric razors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razor#Electric_razors) all use a dragging *shave* action, even if they use multiple blades, while [electric hair clippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_clipper#Electric_clippers) use the cutting *shear* action.

Answer (score 0):

Dogs can have a single coat, typically called hair or a double coat (an under coat and a top coat), typically called fur. Hair is shaved, Fur is sheared.